# Why did season 1 Barry disappear when season 2 Barry saved his mom?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the season 2 finale of *The Flash*, Barry is broken after he lost his dad, after he beat Zoom, so he went back in time to save his mom. And he succeeded.
Then he saw his younger self through the door, he smiled that his mom was okay, but then he disappeared.

So does that mean the season 1 finale events got erased? Because that means no earth 2, no Zoom, no earth 2 wells and no singularity. Why did season 1 Barry disappear when season 2 Barry saved his mom?

Comment: Please edit your question to involve some punctuation, capitalization, and other nice words. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Barry's mum has been now been saved, those events of the first season wouldn't have taken place, because she was alive all along. Similar to the photos vanishing in Back To The Future when Marty changed history.
I would imagine the question of how that affected the whole timeline of season 1 will play out in season 3.